# "Best Practice"/Favourite Pattern for Calling Web Services (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

### Problem:

- We have a web app that calls some web services asynchronously (from the page).
- Normally this is fine, but **some are failing under load test** (due to timeouts).

**What are (if there are any) any suggested "best practices" for calling web services asynchronously in a web application?**

- Are there any patterns that may be of use?
- Should direct calling of services be avoided? (perhaps resorting to some other method such as AJAX)?

*To Illustrate - Direct Calling:*

```
WSNameSpace.WSName svc = new WSNameSpace.WSName();
svc.EventName += new WSNameSpace.EventNameEventHandler(CallbackDelegate);
svc.ServiceMethodAsync(param1, param2);
```

- Should I focus more on improving the exception handling rather than calling the services?

Many thanks.

Rob

#### Update

I have been Googleing and have found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/dphill/articles/43260.aspx) on creating "service agents", while it relates to WinForms, I will definitely have a sit down and read of this later to see how it affects my thoughts on this :)

Comment: Hi Rob - does the Ui need to understand if the result failed?  As you call it Async and all you doing is passing some params - are you really waiting for the result?

Comment: Hi, yes, for example if something went wrong with the service, it returns a failed result, which is then updated in the UI to let the user know.

Comment: The fail - i presume is then out of sync with the rest of the UI, ie the page can continue and you only need to let them know that some(thing) failed and move to process that failure-hence the Aysnc call.IF that is the case - i would AJAX the async call and build in an observer pattern on the fail

Comment: Wanna put that to an answer so people can vote/discuss? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use async call to webservice with async pages.
Something like this http://gofrom.us/6LC

Comment: Thanks for the article, will spend some time later digesting this properly. Looks like it could be very useful. +1 from me.

Comment: That link eventually gets you to http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060918.asp